# How can I clear the overflow for just one line?

Tags: html, css

I'm having problems clearing some overflow between left and right floats.

My overflow goes down deep into the first parent div and I just want it to clear into the next line on the next parent div. Here is my simplified version of my code:

```html
 <div>
      <div style='float:left; display:block;'>
        <div>
          <div style='background-color:blue'>
            asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
          </div>
          <div style='background-color:blue'>
            asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
          </div>
          <div style='background-color:blue'>
            asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
          </div>
          <div style='background-color:red; clear:right'>
            <div style='width:300px; position:relative; display: block; clear: both'>
              asdfasdfasdfasdffadsafasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
            </div>
          </div>
          <div style='background-color:blue'>
            asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
          </div>
          <div style='background-color:blue'>
            asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style='float;right;'>
        <div>
          asdfasdfasdf
        </div>
        <div>
          asdfasdfasdf
        </div>
        <div>
          asdfasdfasdf
        </div>
        <div>
          asdfasdfasdf
        </div>
      </div>
    
    </div>
```

My above example has text overlapping in the same line as the red box. How do I make the overlapping float right text drop down to the next blue box?

Comment: your text inside the red box will always be in the red box, because is its container.
You can make the red box grow, or dealing with overflow with CSS overflow property: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: not sure what the problem is (your example doesn't show it very well - is it the text in red is flowing into the right column?) but you could try using flex instead of floats - floats were never intended for positioning like this and css has moved on a lot so they should not be needed anymore

Comment: also you have a typo error in right float div `float;right;`...it will be `float:right;`

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question easily:

your text inside the red box will always be in the red box, because is its container. So...

You put a widht limit, and the content is bigger than the container. This is known as overflow.

You can make the red box grow, or dealing with overflow with CSS overflow property: w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

If you want to keep your width limit on your divs, you can add a blank div to match the overflowing first col div:

```html
<div>
      <div style='float:left; display:block;'>
        <div>
          <div style='background-color:blue'>
            asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
          </div>
          <div style='background-color:blue'>
            asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
          </div>
          <div style='background-color:blue'>
            asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
          </div>
          <div style='background-color:red; clear:right'>
            <div style='width:300px; clear: both'>
              asdfasdfasdfasdffadsafasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
            </div>
          </div>
          <div style='background-color:blue'>
            asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
          </div>
          <div style='background-color:blue'>
            asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style='float;right;'>
        <div>
          asdfasdfasdf
        </div>
        <div>
          asdfasdfasdf
        </div>
        <div>
          asdfasdfasdf
        </div>
        <div>
        <br>
        </div>
        <div>
          asdfasdfasdf
        </div>
      </div>
    
    </div>
```